# Поиск одинаковых значений в массиве

Tags: c++

Задача - найти одинаковые значения в массиве.
Что не так в коде?

```
void main(void)
{
    int a[5]={1,5,3,4,5},i=0,k;

    for(k=0;k<=4;k++)
    {
        do
        {
            if(a[k]==a[i]){
                printf("%i",a[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        while((i-4)==0);
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void main()
{ int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int i=0;k=0;

for (i=0; i<5; i++) {

      for(k=5;k>i;k-1){

        if(a[i]==a[k]){Напечатать сообщение или убить всех человеков;}
     }
  }
}
```

---

Смысл в том что программа будет сравнивать 1 элемент со всеми в массиве, затем 2ой элемент со всеми и т.д.

Comment: не получается, при выводе похожих элементов выводится весь массив

Comment: Каким методом выводите?

Comment: printf("%i",a[i])

Comment: Аааа... когда i=0, a[i]=1, 1=1 он выводит... Ясно, надо чтобы значения i и k не совпадали, то есть если i=0 то k должен перебираться от 1 до 4 и т.п.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^
исправил

Comment: так вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Дак там и нет одинаковых) сделай a[5]={1,2,3,4,1}
и исправь for(k=5;k>i+1;k-1)

Comment: все понял
for(k=(i+1);k<5;k++)
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в этой строке: `while((i-4)==0);`. Замени её на `while(i<5);`, а также инициализируй i нулём во внешнем цикле перед do. Ты хоть пробовал сам ошибку искать? Перед тем, как запускать код, надо прокрутить алгоритм у себя в голове. Сразу наткнёшься на то, что в while будет сравниваться -4 с 0, и цикл прекратится.

Исправленный вариант должен работать, но мне он не очень нравится. Зачем мешать разные циклы? Цикл do ... while выполняется всегда, как минимум, один раз, независимо от условия. Здесь это не нужно, можно обойтись двумя for, как тебе написали выше.